# How to install the specific version of postgres?

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I need to install a **postgres 9.6.6** on Ubuntu 14.04, but the command

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

installes  **9.6.7**.

How can I install 9.6.6?

An output of command

```
apt-cache policy postgresql-9.6
```

is

```
postgresql-9.6:
  Installed: 9.6.7-1.pgdg14.04+1
  Candidate: 9.6.7-1.pgdg14.04+1
  Version table:
 *** 9.6.7-1.pgdg14.04+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: This would be better asked on a different stackexchange site like `askubuntu.com`. [Here's a Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package/428778) from that site should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to install this version from the repository. You'll need to install it from source code, which can be nasty :-) Don't forget that postgres 10 is quite sexy and has a bunch of kickass features ;-)

Answer (score 18):

You can install a specific version using the PostgreSQL Development Group maintained repo.

For Ubuntu 18.04

- Create the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list and add this line for the repository:

`deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main`

- Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

After this, you can now do: `sudo apt-get install postgresql-10` or adapt it for your desired version. See more [here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/)

Comment: `pgdg` does not contains minor versions. I just made an attempt to install 11.12 - only 11.13 is available

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem to restore db from backup for older minor version.
It seams, that there are three solutions:

1. use latest minor version from repo (and pray for stability working)
2. build from src (as Laurenz mentioned, that's hard path)
3. use [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/tags?page=1&ordering=-name&name=15) with exactly specific postgresql version (just mount volumes PGDATA, configs, not very difficult) -
   docker container is enough to check backup consistency and good for manage and administrate.

Comment: You don't need to pray, minor updates are always binary compatible and introduce no new behavior.

Answer (score -6):

You should always install the latest minor release for each version, so don't install 9.6.6.

The binary downloads from the PostgreSQL Development Group only provide the latest release for each version (at least for the RPM packages; there is a repository for older Debian packages).

If you really need 9.6.6, you might have to install it from source.

Comment: That may be a problem since, unlike the semantic versioning may indicate, PostgreSQL patches may induce breaking changes, even if the major.minor version is the same. There was a time that they broke retroactive compatibility with backups on all major.minor versions due to a security bugfix.

Comment: I emphatically disagree. PostgreSQL doesn't use semantic versioning at all, but we strictly avoid *any* changes in behavior in minor releases (except bug fixes). I assume you are talking about the [fix for CVE-2018-1058](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=582edc369cdbd348d68441fc50fa26a84afd0c1a). That was **not** a breaking change. What it **did** break was the restore of objects that use ill-defined functions that can be used for privilege escalation, which is the least invasive fix. If you don't want to upgrade because you rely on buggy behavior, ...

Comment: It was not that we were relying on buggy behavior: we needed to restore backups made on older versions, but the tool was refusing to restore them. The backup file, itself, probably wasn't making use of any bugs, but the newer tool was refusing to restore it.

Comment: Those backups were not safe to restore.

Comment: Regardless, we had to install older versions in order to restore the backups.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is correct that it's impossible to install a specific version from `pgdg`. I just made an attempt to install 11.12 - it's not possible only 11.13 is available