# Howto install PostgreSQL 9.6.6 using apt-get on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, apt-get

Is it possible to use apt-get to install a very specific version of PostgreSQL. I would like to install PostgreSQL **9.6.6**. I followed the instructions on the [postgres download](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) page. This will get the current latest version which is **9.6.7**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need an outdated version? But you can't install that from the repository. You need to download the source code and compile yourself.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48868156/6464308.

Comment: then i will install from source, thanks for pointing me to the article i didn't find before.