# Error 'postgres.h: No such file or directory' when installing Apache AGE from the latest release

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I am trying to install Apache AGE by following the instructions provided in the [documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/setup.html). However, I was only able to install it from the source code. When I attempted to install Postgres 12 from a package manager and downloaded the latest official release of AGE (version 1.1.0), I found the following error:

```bash
src/backend/age.c:20:10: fatal error: postgres.h: No such file or directory
   20 | #include "postgres.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: src/backend/age.o] Error 1
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS and have followed all the steps in the documentation, including setting the `PG_CONFIG` variable. Could someone please advise me on whether I am doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

It can be because your path to postgres.h is not right. It's mostly inside the server folder inside postgresql folder. You can just run the command `pg_config` to check your server and postgresql path (Also run the command `sudo apt install postgresql-server-dev-XX` where `XX` is your postgresql version to install postgresql-server-dev package) and can check where postgres.h is (which I found inside server folder) and then correct the path if not.

In my case the original path was

```
/usr/include/postgresql/12/server/postgres.h
```

while in pg_config `INCLUDEDIR-SERVER` was pointing out to

```
/usr/include/postgresql/server
```

so I moved the server folder and it worked. You can check out this post for more info: [How to fix 'postgres.h' file not found problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724622/how-to-fix-postgres-h-file-not-found-problem)